C# XML streaming and losing control over node names in specific cases
Streaming a list is simple and comes with full control over xml node names.
But that control is not available in some cases. Here are three examples.
Cases A and B is what normaly works (but what I do not want to use).
Case C also works but with loosing control over the xml node names. (And I want to use this with control over node names).
Note: The problem in C is avoidable by implementing IXmlSerializable but that is a lot of extra work for what seems to be a small problem.
For example A:
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("my_names_list"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(string), ElementName = "my_name")]
    public List<string> MyNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

With this xml as a possible result.
<root>
    <my_names_list>
        <my_name>first value</my_name>
        <my_name>second value</my_name>
    </my_names_list>
</root>

or B
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "my_name")]
    public List<string> MyNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

with this xml
<root>
    <my_name>first value</my_name>
    <my_name>second value</my_name>
</root>

But I have a problem (on control over the list element node names) in the following case C. How can I set the node name of the list elements?
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class MyClass : List<string> { }

This will only produce the following, no matter that tags you try.
<root>
    <string>first value</string>
    <string>second value</string>
</root>

In code exmples A and B have a member which is a list, which is not what I want to use.
For streaming A is what I prefere in most cases and B is what I prefer in sometimes.
In code example C there is no class member for the list, the class is inheriting from a list, which is what I want to use.
In this example string in List<string> is not realy that big of a problem. But a List<MyClassWithTheUglyLongNamy> is more iritating, or I have to make consessions in my coding style or I have to accept the xml streaming results. Or I can try to find a way to control/direct the XML parser in c#. (I know I can do this with IXmlSerializable but that is a lot of extra work for one name change.)
For streaming C I have lost control over the list element node name. Whatever I try to change that, the compiler is accepting none of it.
How can I use the coding from example C and get the streaming results from example B without using IXmlSerializable?
Any advise is welcome.

Just one more note, XmlAttributeOverrides can not be used to set a name for items in the list of case C.

This 'question' gives a nice overview and (to my oppinion) can not be answered. There is no solution for the problem (other than implementing IXmlSerialisable.)
I consider this as 'closed'.
